# How to let the user know that they have logout in django?

Tags: django

I have used the following code snippet to logout the user from the session.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_page(request):
   logout(request)
   return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Question> I need to notify the user that he/she has successfully logout. How can I do that in django?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i guess you could redirect them to a `thanks for logging out` page instead of `/`

you may also want to have a look at the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/)